# Jquery drag&drop fired both stop and drop events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I would that when I dropped the element is not fired the stop event.
Here the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/keepyourweb/TfpYW/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.drag').draggable({
    stop: function(e, ui) {
         alert('stop drag!');   
    }

}).droppable({
    accept: '.drag',
    drop: function(e, ui) {
         alert('dropped!');   
    }

});
```